# HTTPS request can't verify certificate on  iOS Safari

Tags: ios, https, mobile-safari, ssl-certificate

I didn't configure the HTTPS on my domain so I'm not really sure where to start with this warning prompt that I only get on iOS Safari on my iPhone and iPad. I've never gotten this on a desktop with Mac Safari, Chrome, FF, or IE.

Can someone point me to a file on my ubuntu/apache EC2 server or somewhere on the site of my domain provider, GoDaddy, that deals with verifying certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the link](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/05/11/godaddy-ssl-certificates-and-cannot-verify-identity-on-macsafari/) which solved my problem.

I needed to put **BOTH** .crt files from GoDaddy into my /etc/apache2/ssl folder on my apache EC2 server and add the following to my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle.crt
```

Answer (score 8):

For those on Nginx you need to append the gd_bundle.crt file to your other .crt cert. Just `cat  gd_bundle.crt >> yourwebsite.crt` and restart Nginx.

Comment: You are the Life Saver! just had to wrap it with `bash -c` : `sudo bash -c 'cat gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt >> public.pem'`

Answer (score 2):

Tim,

If browsers on desktops are showing the SSL without warning, and the warning you are getting is on a mobile device, the issue is most likely with the intermediate certificate of the Certificate Authority that issued the SSL not being installed properly.  I suggest that you contact the issuer of the certificate for help with this and not the host or the domain registrar.

Comment: thanks Mike, GoDaddy has my certificates and this helped get the ball rolling to find the solution (listed below). thanks,