# forwarding http to https doesn't work on iOS Safari

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, safari, http-status-code-301

I am forwarding my http traffic to https with a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This works everywhere except on iOS safari.  When I go to the http address on iOS safari, the browser hangs because there is no where to go with http.

What can I do to forward http to https on iOS Safari?

Comment: Does it come up with an error message at all?

Comment: @thickguru It says: "safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding.

Comment: Take a look at this @atma [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196783/https-request-cant-verify-certificate-on-ios-safari) might help.

Comment: @thickguru my cert is fine, my site loads no problem when I go straight to https. The problem is when I go to http, the redirect does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the .htaccess didn't have a 301 redirect.  Once I added that, everything redirected smooth:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: i have the same problem. when adding the NC,R=301 i get a bad request :(